# Fluctuation in iPhone Screen when trying to open mapview

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, screen, alertview

I have an app which has a functionality such that when a certain button is pressed, an alert view pops up asking for certain login credentials. When submitted, a web is called which returns that latitude and longitude which are then plotted on the mapview. In case the lat and long are not available, the user sees an alert. Till this stage all goes well. But when I press the cancel button on the second alert the iphone screen fluctuates. After that whenever I navigate to any other page, the screen fluctuates. When the sent to background and then brought to foreground again, it starts working fine. what can be the problem?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question about the implementation done in cancel button action? This could be a problem of mapview delegate methods are not handled properly. Best Regards.

Comment: calcel button does nothin. it just closes the alert.

Comment: "When submitted, a web is called which returns that latitude and longitude which are then plotted on the mapview." what does it mean?

Comment: there are two alerts. first one requires login credentials. if login is successful, it calls a webservice which returns a location as longitude and latitude. but some times the service does not return anything. in that case the second alert box appears. second aler box has no functionality behind it